# How do I download this file? Flash Paper

Tags: javascript, html, flash, adobe

How can I download this file and create a PDF?

http://data.lidi.s3.amazonaws.com/conecte2015/LetoWeb.html?bookId=MAT1_MI_Student#

Comment: This isn’t really programming related, is it?

Comment: You can't download it. It's a Flash app (swf) that loads multiple other swf files as _containers_ of pages. Also it **only works when it's running from their server** (a Flash file can check its location). Find the "Developer Tools" of your browser. In Chrome or Firefox you can see the locations of loaded files, if possible, save each swf page & find an online _swf to jpg_ converter.